# How to rotate the view?

Tags: microsoft-visio, microsoft-visio-2013

With a Visio document, it's (still) easy to zoom and pan within the page.  But how do you rotate the view?  That is, look at it from a different side — not change the drawing itself, just like zooming doesn't change the shapes but just the way you look at them in the window.

BTW, selecting all and rotating the shapes as a group does not work because of shapes that are specific to horiz or vertical placement; in particular the dimension line labeling.

Comment: Okay. So it is literally just the *view* of the page you are wanting to change rather than objects or physical page orientation.  I can't think of any way to do that at the moment outside of using your graphics card configuration tool to rotate the whole display, most of them do that for you.  I don't have access to Visio at the moment but I can have a looksee on Monday if no one else gives you an answer in the meantime.  I'll delete my earlier comments.

Answer (score 2):

- Zoom out to see the full page
- Hover the cursor over the top right corner of the page while holding down the control key.  The cursor should change to an arrow going in a circle.
- You can then rotate the page. Anything on the page will also rotate. The angle of the page should show in the status bar.

Source: http://www.officefrustration.com/showthread.php?p=3734516

Comment: This works only with older versions of Visio. Unfortunately, with Visio 2010 and Visio 2013 page rotation is no longer available.

Comment: That's good to know. I am upgrading to Visio 2013 next week. If I can figure out a solution for newer versions, I will update the answer.

Comment: This works for me with Visio 2010.

Answer (score 1):

[This thread](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/91a0e155-ba45-446f-8afb-a701cebc4eaf/visio-need-to-capture-and-rotate-entire-drawing-180-degrees?forum=visiogeneral) contains the solution.

To sum it up:

1. Using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> to capture all.
2. On the "Home" tab, in the "Arrange" group.
3. Drop down "Group", and select "Group"
4. Click Status bar, click Angle to open the "Size & Position" window.
5. In the "Size & Position" window, change Angle to 180 deg.

I'm using Visio 2013, and I was successful in doing this.

Comment: I see: rotate a group, not the loose shapes, and the "smart" stuff going on (e.g. dimension lines) behave locally to the group.  Then everything is inside a group, making the document more awkward to work with.

Answer (score 0):

Go to "DESIGN" tab
left hand corner, there is an orientation button. You can toggle back and forth from landscape and portrait here.

Comment: Is this something new?

Comment: I think he refers to page orientation, which affect print settings. But this will only affects the white background, not the drawings.